# If $f$ is a positive function and $\int_{E}f d\lambda = 0$ then $\lambda (E) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, topological-groups

If $f$ is a positive function and 
$$
\int_{E}f d\lambda = 0,
$$ 
then show that $\lambda (E) = 0$ where  $\lambda $ is a Haar (Radon) measure.

I know that if $f$ is a positive function and $\int_{E}f d\lambda = 0$ then $\lambda ^ \ast = 0 $ ($\lambda ^ \ast$  is the outer measure) but I can't show that $\lambda (E)$ is zero. Note: $E\subseteq G$ and $G$ is topological group.

Comment: If $E$ is measurable, then $\lambda(E)\le\lambda^*(E)$. If $E$ is not measurable, then the integral over $E$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: In principle of analysis of ALiprantis we have $ \lambda ^*(E)\le\lambda(E) $ but we haven't nothing about $\lambda(E)\le\lambda^*(E)$.

Comment: With the *outer* measure? I'd be surprised.

Comment: the above statement is in aliprantis page 107.In folland Real analysis page 213 we have $\lambda ^*(U) = \lambda (U) $ if U is open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
E_1=\{x\in E: f(x)\le 1\},
$$
and 
$$
E_n=\{x\in E : 2^{-n+2}> f(x)\ge 2^{-n+1}\}.
$$
Clearly, the $E_n$ are disjoint, measurable, $E=\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ and thus
$$
\lambda(E)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda(E_n).
$$
It suffices to show that $\lambda(E_n)=0$, for all $n$. But as $f(x)>0$, for all $x\in E$,
$$
\int_E f\,d\lambda \ge \int_{E_n}f\,d\lambda\ge\int_{E_n} 2^{-n+1}d\lambda=2^{-n+1}\lambda(E_n),
$$
which implies that $\lambda(E_n)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

On that page of Aliprantis, $\mu$ is just a set-function, and $\mu^*$ is the outer measure it generates.  Indeed $\mu^*(E) \le \mu(E)$ in that setting, and equality may not hold.  For example, in the real line, $\mu(E)$ could be the diameter of the set $E$, and then for $\mu^*$ we get Lebesgue outer measure.

Of course when we write $\int_E f\;d\lambda$ we assume $\lambda$ is a measure, not just any set-function.

Comment: thanks. I don't notice that.